# How can I best inform my compiler to deal with nested loops with complicated indexing on large arrays in C for optimal perfomance?

Tags: c, large-data, hpc, scientific-computing

I am working with a scientific optimization problem in what we might consider 3+1-dimensional space, where the extra dimension is described by a tensor represented in the program by either coefficients or angular segmentation, along with elevation and azimuth coordinates. In a typical case I might need to deal effectively with multiple arrays (of doubles) of dimensions along the lines of `75 x 75 x 75 x 16` and potentially intermediate ones as large as `75 x 75 x 75 x 16 x 16` when involving both and coefficient representations. I have to do mostly real and some complex arithmetic and trigonometry with reasonable efficiency to do things like upsampling, projecting from and into two dimensions, and numerical differentiation. I may be able to make a more convenient algorithm in the future, but currently, this is what my method looks like.

To do these things I have written a C implementation of about 1500 lines where I use a combination of MKL functions where applicable, and resort to nested loops otherwise. The problem here is that the loops have to deal with large arrays of sizes that are (as things are now) unknown at compile time in nested loops with complicated indexing. Thus what I get when I try to analyze performance using a perf report is what looks like apparently random (but in fact consistent) bottlenecks for some operations (say, multiplying and summing over two vectors of above dimensions in some slightly complicated way, like some expansion over the innermost dimension) but no bottlenecks for similar ones. This seems to correlate with various storage-related errors that sugggests to me that the compiled code is not truly optimized for such large arrays. For reference, I currently do the computations on an AMD Ryzen 3900 with one physical core per thread; the algorithm is parallelizable at essentially a "top" level (all the significant arithmetic and such is done by each core individually).

So essentially, the question is, what should my strategy for performance improvements be? I have two basic ideas: one is to replace the dimension variables with macros that I set and compile at runtime through my planned master script. This isn't a problem on the implementation side as far as I'm concerned. This way at least the compiler will have information about the sizes in numerical terms, though I don't know how much the compiler will make use of this type of information. Any input here is appreciated.

The second approach I can think of would be, basically, if I have any other means of telling the compiler, "hey, this is a big number, so this array will be large, treat accordingly" that allows it to take this into consideration? I'm using GCC at the moment but open to using other compilers.

Or any other general mitigation strategies for large arrays would also be welcome.

An example of what a snippet my code looks like with generic parameters inserted would be something like

```
for(int j = 0;j<ALL_3D_SPACE;j++)
{
    for (int k = 0; k< DIM_4_1; k++)
    {
        for (int l = 0; l< DIM_4_2; l++)
        {
            REDUCED_SUM[j*DIM_4_1 +k] += EXPANDED_SUM[j*DIM_4_2*DIM_4_1+k*DIM_4_2+l]*COEFFS[j*DIM_4_2+l];
        }   
    }
}
```

Various data structures are declared in the standard pointer-malloc way, e.g. following the above mock example:

```
double * EXPANDED_SUM, *COEFFS, REDUCED_SUM;
EXPANDED_SUM = (double*) malloc(sizeof(double)*ALL_3D_SPACE*DIM_4_2*DIM_4_1);
COEFFS = (double*) malloc(sizeof(double)*ALL_3D_SPACE*DIM_4_2);
REDUCED_SUM = (double*) malloc(sizeof(double)*ALL_3D_SPACE*DIM_4_1);
```

I reuse structures as much as possible and free them when they are no longer needed.

The *anticipated* use-case has the user input a set of ~100 2D projections of about size `nX*nY*DIM_4_1`, dimensional and other parameters, where `ALL_3D_SPACE = nX*nY*nZ` and DIM_4_1 is of the order 10-20, and nX, nY and nZ are all circa 50-100. The expected output would be (3+1)D reconstructions of size `ALL_3D_SPACE*(DIM_4_2+2)` where DIM_4_2 is of the order 5-10.  Currently both the input and output are handled as text files. Note that any comparisons to the input are a very small part of the code and that the vast majority of it is arithmetic/numeric differentiation along the above lines. The actual core error function that handles almnost all of the processing takes projections and present estimate of output as inputs, and when needed outputs an error, as well as gradients for a better estimate of the output for use by an optimizing routine.

Comment: Including your current declaration of the actual data structure would be helpful, as well as a brief use-case. Otherwise this ends up very broad and vague.

Comment: @Lundin I am not sure how much it will help because it is inherently a broad and vague matter, but I did my best. I can't really describe a "true" use-case (not least because dozens of parameters need to be specified) but I added my best attempts at describing what the input and oputput would look like, as well as what my declarations of data structures look like.

Comment: One thing you could do, if you only have a few 100 items is to drop malloc in favour for static arrays. Then from there ponder cache usage and how different threads iterate across the arrays. I suspect that the various floating point calculations will be the major bottleneck, but every little bit helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you use arrays that big I suggest to store them to the heap or as global variables. The stack will explode with that kind of sizes